# Large file downloads via Asp.net Web Api accessing third party API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm developing a set of ASP.Net Web APIs to integrate a third party document management system into an existing CMS.  The third party has a set of API calls to enable this.   I've got most of the integration working, but downloading a document is very slow.  This looks to be  because when I make the call for the download.  The file downloads from the third party to the webserver, then from the webserver to the client.

I'm trying to avoid a direct call to the third party api for security reasons.  Is there a way I can allow my endpoint act as a Proxy for the third party api. Allowing the file stream to pass directly to the client?

```
    public static  HttpResponseMessage GetDocument(string docId, string docName)
                {

                    HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                    var stream = getDocumentStream(docId, docName);

                    result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
                    result.Content.Headers.ContentType =
                        new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
                    result.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + docName + "\"");


                    return result;
                }

 public static Stream getDocumentStream(string docId,string name)
        {
            var UriTemplate = ApiUri;
            var ParamTemplate = "name=" + name + "&documentId=" + docId;
            var userName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EdeskUserName"];
            var passWord = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EdeskPWD"];
            return EDeskDataUtility.EdeskAPIDownload(UriTemplate, ParamTemplate, userName, passWord);

        }



         public static Stream DownloadFile(string URI, string Parameters)
                {
                    WebResponse resp = GetURIResponse(URI, Parameters);
                    if (resp == null) return null;
                    return resp.GetResponseStream();

                }



                public static System.Net.WebResponse GetURIResponse(string URI, string Parameters)
                {
                    System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(URI);
                    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                    req.Method = "POST";

                    //We need to count how many bytes we're sending. Post'ed Faked Forms should be name=value&
                    byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Parameters);
                    req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
                    System.IO.Stream os = req.GetRequestStream();
                    os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length); //Push it out there
                    os.Close();
                   var resp = req.GetResponse();
                    return resp;
                }
```

Comment: yeah what you are doing would be slower compared to directly getting from the 3rd party...i don't know about proxy stuff...but if it helps can you see if you your call to the 3rd party api is buffering the entire file from the response i.e the call to `EdeskApiDownload`...if the file is large this would consume lot of memory...instead you should see if you can use their api to not buffer the response stream and supply the stream directly to StreamContent...also if your 3rd party exposes Async api, you should use that as your scenario definitely could use it to improve server performance...

Comment: Wouldn't it be more appropriate to write code to authorize the call to the third party rather than get in the way in this manner?

Comment: continuing on my previous comment: if the `EdeskApiDownload` api provides an unbuffered access to the stream, this is good because if you supply the resposnestream directly to StreamContent, then it keeps 'pulling' the data from 3rd party...couple of advantages here are: you wouldn't be buffering the entire file, which saves memory usage and also your are not blocked until the whole file gets buffered...